# TabBar rotation from portrait to landscape

Tags: iphone

I am making a TabBar based universal app. I have added few extra tabs  and changed the viewController to navigationController. Now when i am trying to rotate the view from portrait to landscape, its rotating the inside view but tabBar does not rotate and it stays at the same place ie at the bottom of the portrait mode where as every other UI are rotating properly.

Comment: The answer to this question is [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242849/uitabbar-orientation-problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the controller not supporting the rotation (respectively its owner) overrides shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and returns YES for all orientations.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
#pragma unused(interfaceOrientation)
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return YES;
}
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW23

Comment: i have checked every thing but still the same result.