# UITabbar orientation problem

Tags: iphone, rotation, orientation, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am working on orientation work on uitabbar application. I am using 5 tabbar item in tabbar. I want only 4 tab bar item to be rotated in both Landscape and potrait. but the issue is when i put "return no" to shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in non rotating tabbar item, all tab bar are not working. can anybody please tell me what i went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
sathish

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, a UITabBarController will only return YES to the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: message if every one of its child controllers returns YES to that message.  The behavior you're seeing is the expected behavior.

Check out the fourth list item on [this page.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1688.html)

Comment: Thanks adam for your reply. You mean i have to make UITabBarController custom and declare shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to NO over there.

Comment: You could try to subclass UITabBarController and customize how it handles rotation.  I haven't done that, but I don't see any obvious reason it wouldn't work.  I would be certain that this is the user experience you want though; I think I would be confused if the app rotated on some tabs but not on others.